# Setting the value of an unsigned char * in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I've got a function that takes an unsigned char * as a parameter, but the data I'm being sent is throwing a type mismatch error.

```
int main()
  {
  Queue * queue = newQueue ();
  addByteToQueue (queue, 1);
  addByteToQueue (queue, 2);
  addByteToQueue (queue, 3);
  return 0;
  }

void addByteToQueue (Queue * queue, unsigned char * byte)
  {
  // stuff
  }
```

Visual studio is counting the 1/2/3 in the function calls as integers, which makes sense to me.  As a test, I also tried doing this:

```
unsigned char * a = 1;
```

Similar error.  Now, I can't change the function prototype.  Assuming I'm being sent bad data in the call, how *would* one go about assigning the value of an unsigned char pointer?  Alternatively, is there some other crucial thing I'm missing that would make this work the way it is?

Comment: I suggest looking up: 1. What is a pointer? 2. how to get a pointer from an object. 3. What is the type of a literal such as `2`.

Comment: `addByteToQueue` indicates adding a single byte to a queue of bytes. The `unsigned char*` argument indicates adding a fixed number of bytes from a buffer, to the queue. These are incompatible. The design is bollocks. Don't use it.

Comment: Or, maybe as is usual on SO, the `addByteToQueue` signature you show is not the real one. If so, then kindly desist from posting meaningless questions.

Comment: To get a pointer to an `unsigned char` you first have to *have* an `unsigned char` in the program.

Comment: Read the documentation of the queue. It is abnormal to expect a pointer to a byte , when just adding a byte, so the documentation may be enlightening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in the original version of the addByteToQueue prototype, which led to all the pointer confusion.  Here's the correct version, with a bit more of the code filled in:

```
class Queue
  {
  private:

    unsigned char queue[1024];
    int first = 0;
    int last = -1;

  public:

    void add (unsigned char b)
      {
      // adding to the queue
      }
  };

Queue * newQueue ();
void enqueue_byte (Queue * q, unsigned char b);

int main()
  {
  Queue * queue = newQueue ();
  addByteToQueue (queue, 1);
  addByteToQueue (queue, 2);
  addByteToQueue (queue, 3);
  return 0;
  }

Queue * newQueue ()
  {
  Queue * queue = new Queue ();
  return queue;
  }

// "unsigned char byte" instead of "unsigned char * byte"
void addByteToQueue (Queue * queue, unsigned char byte)
  {
  queue->add (byte);
  }
```

I'm surprised it let me assign an integer to an unsigned char without some type of conversion, but it seems I'm learning a lot about C++ today.

Another solution would have been to keep the pointer param and modify the function call to be:

```
  unsigned char byte = 0;
  addByteToQueue (queue, &byte);
```

In this case, however, this would have broken things for other people using the class.

Thanks to the people who commented and added answers.  This took a lot more reading and staring than I'd care to admit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're using that how it's intended.

Try something like this

```
int main()
{
  Queue * queue = newQueue ();
  unsigned char data[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  for (auto&& byte : data)
  {
      addByteToQueue (queue, &byte);
  }
  return 0;
}

void addByteToQueue (Queue * queue, unsigned char *)
{
  // stuff
}
```

Basically, the char* wants to be pointing into some data blob. You can't pass literals into a function that takes pointers directly.

Comment: Why `auto &&` but not `auto &`?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the **pointer** to an unsigned char to 1, 2, 3.
That is, you are telling the program that an unsigned char value can be found **in memory at the address "1" (or "2" or...)**.

What you need to do is pass on the pointer to an **actually existing** unsigned char in memory.
Since it is unclear what you actually want to be doing with all this or why you need an unsigned char*, here is a very simple example:

```
unsigned char* test = new unsigned char(); // Create an unsigned char in the heap, note that you need to delete it later or it will be memory leak
*test = 60;  // Assign a value to it
addByteToQueue(queue, test);
```